# Filter org-mode agenda by tag

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to work with org-mode to create a simple list of upcoming events. In my org file, I tag all events as :event: and SCHEDULED. However, events are not the only thing that is labeled SCHEDULED and I don't want to see all of that at once.

So I tried to use the code below to modify the normal agenda to only show items labled event, but it doesn't filter the list at all. I also can't seem to find any information on the command (org-agenda-filter-by-tag) except that it exists and doesn't cause an error in my .emacs file...

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
     '(("o" "Upcoming" (
            ;; agenda with only items tagged event  
            (agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 14)
                  (org-agenda-filter-by-tag "event")
                  (org-deadline-warning-days 0)
             ))
       )) 
))
```

Once I get that working, I am going to try to add anything labled DEADLINE to the list as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
(org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("+event"))
```

instead of the

```
(org-agenda-filter-by-tag "event")
```

(source: http://orgmode.org/manual/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html#fn-1 )

Comment: As is written in [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18233/39432) `org-agenda-tag-filter-preset`  is designed to work agenda-wide and can't be usefully set per-block, use the solution in attached link to filter agenda by tag

Answer (score 0):

To list all headlines tagged :event:, add the current file to the list of agenda buffers with C-c [, do M-x org-agenda, select option m (Match a TAGS/PROP/TODO query), type event at the prompt and press return.

Comment: Thanks. I've figured out how to do it with key board commands, but I want to do it with a custom-command in my .emacs so I can string multiple commands to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      (quote (("e" "Upcoming" tags "event"))))
```